# Magento 2 how to get row total with discount?

Tags: magento2, cart, discount, subtotal

Normally in Magento 2 **cart page** show **subtotal**. But I would like to get **subtotal** after **deducting discount** if any cart **rules applied** or **coupon** code applied to any **product**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the final row total of the item in the cart by this code

```
echo $_item->getRowTotal() - $_item->getDiscountAmount();
```

where the $_item is the Cart Quote Item

Answer (score 3):

With taxes and rounding penny issue:

```
($item->getRowTotal()-$item->getDiscountAmount()+$item->getTaxAmount()+$item->getDiscountTaxCompensationAmount())
```